# Algorithm to find the Binary in Terms of 1 and 2 for an Integer

Tags: algorithm, math, binary, automata

### Problem

In developing a virtual deterministic finite automata, I'm trying to create an algorithm that outputs unique binary strings from decimal values. The decimal value from the binary is found by multiplying the appropriate exponentiation of 2 by either 1 or 2. For instance,

```
    19 becomes:
    1    2    1    1
```

Since:

```
    2^3  2^2  2^1  2^0
    1    2    1    1
  * __________________
    8  + 8  + 2  + 1
```

### Attempts

#### Attempt 1

I've tried a variety of algorithms, but this one has come the closest:

```
def decToBin2(dec):
    bin = ''
    while dec > 0:
        bin = str(dec % 2) + bin
        dec = dec/2
    return bin
```

However, the binary solutions using this function **include 0**, which **should not occur**. Hence, I've been struggling a bit.

#### Attempt 2

Rory Daulton helped me a great deal with this one, and here's the implementation of his solution and a test run. However, it's failing for a few integers.

```
def decToBin2(dec):
    if dec == 0:
        return ''

    bin = ''
    # Find the largest power of 2 that is less than dec
    fac = 0
    while 2**(fac) <= dec:
        fac = fac + 1
    fac -= 1

    # Subtract that power of 2 and add 1
    dec = dec - 2**(fac) + 1

    # Convert to binary, but 0s become 1s and 1s become 2s
    while dec > 0:
        bin = str(dec % 2 + 1) + bin
        dec = dec/2

    # Pad the left side with 1s
    while len(bin) < fac:
        bin = '1' + bin

    return bin
```

Test Run:

```
✓ 0 = 0 : 
✗ 1 != 2 : 2
✓ 2 = 2 : 2
✗ 3 != 5 : 21
✓ 4 = 4 : 12
✓ 5 = 5 : 21
✓ 6 = 6 : 22
✗ 7 != 11 : 211
✓ 8 = 8 : 112
✓ 9 = 9 : 121
✓ 10 = 10 : 122
✓ 11 = 11 : 211
✓ 12 = 12 : 212
✓ 13 = 13 : 221
✓ 14 = 14 : 222
✗ 15 != 23 : 2111
✓ 16 = 16 : 1112
✓ 17 = 17 : 1121
✓ 18 = 18 : 1122
✓ 19 = 19 : 1211
✓ 20 = 20 : 1212
✓ 21 = 21 : 1221
✓ 22 = 22 : 1222
✓ 23 = 23 : 2111
✓ 24 = 24 : 2112
✓ 25 = 25 : 2121
✓ 26 = 26 : 2122
✓ 27 = 27 : 2211
✓ 28 = 28 : 2212
✓ 29 = 29 : 2221
✓ 30 = 30 : 2222
✗ 31 != 47 : 21111
✓ 32 = 32 : 11112
✓ 33 = 33 : 11121
✓ 34 = 34 : 11122
✓ 35 = 35 : 11211
✓ 36 = 36 : 11212
✓ 37 = 37 : 11221
✓ 38 = 38 : 11222
✓ 39 = 39 : 12111
✓ 40 = 40 : 12112
✓ 41 = 41 : 12121
✓ 42 = 42 : 12122
✓ 43 = 43 : 12211
✓ 44 = 44 : 12212
✓ 45 = 45 : 12221
✓ 46 = 46 : 12222
✓ 47 = 47 : 21111
✓ 48 = 48 : 21112
✓ 49 = 49 : 21121
✓ 50 = 50 : 21122
✓ 51 = 51 : 21211
✓ 52 = 52 : 21212
✓ 53 = 53 : 21221
✓ 54 = 54 : 21222
✓ 55 = 55 : 22111
✓ 56 = 56 : 22112
✓ 57 = 57 : 22121
✓ 58 = 58 : 22122
✓ 59 = 59 : 22211
✓ 60 = 60 : 22212
✓ 61 = 61 : 22221
✓ 62 = 62 : 22222
✗ 63 != 95 : 211111
✓ 64 = 64 : 111112
✓ 65 = 65 : 111121
✓ 66 = 66 : 111122
✓ 67 = 67 : 111211
✓ 68 = 68 : 111212
✓ 69 = 69 : 111221
✓ 70 = 70 : 111222
✓ 71 = 71 : 112111
✓ 72 = 72 : 112112
✓ 73 = 73 : 112121
✓ 74 = 74 : 112122
✓ 75 = 75 : 112211
✓ 76 = 76 : 112212
✓ 77 = 77 : 112221
✓ 78 = 78 : 112222
✓ 79 = 79 : 121111
✓ 80 = 80 : 121112
✓ 81 = 81 : 121121
✓ 82 = 82 : 121122
✓ 83 = 83 : 121211
✓ 84 = 84 : 121212
✓ 85 = 85 : 121221
✓ 86 = 86 : 121222
✓ 87 = 87 : 122111
✓ 88 = 88 : 122112
✓ 89 = 89 : 122121
✓ 90 = 90 : 122122
✓ 91 = 91 : 122211
✓ 92 = 92 : 122212
✓ 93 = 93 : 122221
✓ 94 = 94 : 122222
✓ 95 = 95 : 211111
✓ 96 = 96 : 211112
✓ 97 = 97 : 211121
✓ 98 = 98 : 211122
✓ 99 = 99 : 211211
✓ 100 = 100 : 211212
```

### Helpful Snippet

To test your solution function, you can input your binary string into this function I wrote, which multiplies each exponentiation of 2 by its weight.

```
def binToDec(bin):
    if bin == '':
        return 0
    return binToDec(bin[1:]) + (2**(len(bin) - 1) * int(bin[0]))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a much simpler solution.

## Code

```
def decToBin2(dec):
    bin = ''
    while dec > 0:
        summand = 2 if dec % 2 == 0 else 1
        bin = str(summand) + bin
        dec = (dec - summand)/2
    return bin
```

## Explanation:

Assume an integer d to be converted in binary representation and an empty string b. If d is even, let an integer m be 2 (that is, d mod 2 is equal to 0). Otherwise, let an integer m be 1. Concatenate m to the beginning of b (b = mb). Then, subtract m from b and divide this solution by 2. Repeat the aforementioned steps while b is greater than 0.

## Example:

```
dec = 11
11 = ___ * 2 + ___ becomes:
11 = 5 * 2 + 1 <- LSB
5 = 2 * 2 + 1
2 = 0 * 2 + 2 <- MSB
bin = 211
```

Comment: If you think about it, you may notice that logically your solution is the same as @RoryDaulton. You just merged two(three) loops into one. In Rory's solution the first loop is used to calculate the power, the second to do the conversion and the main line in that loop is `summand = dec % 2` which is logically the same as `summand = 1 if dec % 2 == 1 else 0` and the third loop is used to add back `1`. If you try to merge second and third loops, you'll get `summand = (1 if (dec - 1) % 2 == 1 else 0) + 1` which is logically equivalent to the line you have. And now you don't need the first loop.

Comment: But of course although being logically equivalent, your code is IMHO much simpler than the one for Rory's original solution. I would probably mark this answer as accepted even though it is yours (yes, this is allowed at SO).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is close to finding the standard (0/1) binary representation of a number, so lets just use that. Here is an algorithm--I'll leave the code to you.

First, Consider the numbers that are one less than a power of 2. This is the sequence 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, etc.--you find the next number by multiplying the previous number and adding one. Find the largest number in this sequence that is less than or equal to the given number. For your example of 19 that is 15. Note the position of your number in the sequence. In your example, 15 is the 4th number in the sequence, so remember 4.

Then subtract that number from your given number. Here we get 19 - 15 which is 4.

Convert that calculated number to standard binary--there are multiple, well-known ways to do this, and this is trivial in Python. Prefix this with any needed zeros to get same number of digits as other number (position in the sequence) in the first step. Here We get 100 and we want 4 binary digits so we get 0100.

Finally, replace every 1 in that binary with 2 and every 0 with 1. Here we get 1211, which is the desired result.

This algorithm basically works by noting that subtracting 1 from each digit in  your desired representation results in a standard binary number, one that differs from the given number in a simple way.

A special case in my algorithm is when the given number is one less than a power of 2, so its standard binary representation has no zeros in it. Thus its standard binary is also its special binary and we end up just using its standard binary representation. During my algorithm we change the given number to zero, get a string of zeros, then convert that to a string of ones, which is correct. (This answer was edited to handle this special case.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Rory! I tried implementing your algorithm and it works... for most cases (I edited my question). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The failed cases occur when the binary string increases in length, outputting 2 as the MSB instead of 1.

Comment: Thanks! I've arrived at a solution which I'll soon post. One last thing: mind explaining, in mathematical terms, the line `Then subtract that number from your given number. Here we get 19 - 15 which is 4.`? Why do you do this to arrive at the new "weighted" binary?

Comment: @AnthonyKrivonos The logic is following: we are trying to reduce your problem to a well-known problem of converting a number to binary form. To do that let's split a sequence of `1` and `2` of total length `L` which represents the number `N` into a sum of two numbers: `A1` = a sequence of only `1` of the length `L` and a sequence of `0` and `1` which apparently is just a binary representation of some number(`B`). And the former is just a `2^L-1`. So `B = N - A1` and we know how to convert it. All that is rest is to find `L`, get and convert `B`, and add  `A1` which is add `1` at each position

Comment: @AnthonyKrivonos: Your weighted binary is made of 1s and 2s. If we subtract 1 from each digit we end up with a number made of 0s and 1s, which is regular binary and which we know how to do. So we subtracted the number `1111` (or a different length) from the given number. That number `1111` in binary is one less than a power of 2. You can see that by adding one to it: you end up with all zeros except for the new overflow bit--get get `10000`. This kind of number is a power of 2, in this particular case 2**4. Is that clear?

Comment: @AnthonyKrivonos: The sequence in my first step is just all those binary numbers made only of ones: `0b1 = 1 = 2**1-1`, `0b11 = 3 = 2**2-1`, `0b111 = 7 = 2**3-1`, `0b1111 = 15 = 2**4-1`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! It all makes sense using your method. However, I just came up with a solution that's much lighter and equally as efficient. Please check it out.